# WPF ListBox MouseDoubleClick

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox in a WPF application and I use the event MouseDoubleClick:

```
private void listBoxMain_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textBoxDateiName.Text = listBoxMain.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Question 1: why I get the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Question 2: how can a display in a TextBox the selected item of the ListBox with a simple click and not with DoubleClick?

Thank you for helping

Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly in your xaml, you must bind TextBox to the SelectedItem of ListBox like this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
   //...
</ListBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

If the SelectedItem is an object, you must specify the property to show

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
   //...
</ListBox>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Property}"/>
```